# Counting permutations defined by a simple process

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Consider $n$ labeled balls, $k$ of which are red and $(n-k)$ blue. Given a permutation of these balls, we tick $n-1$ times. For the $i$-th tick, if the $i$-th ball in the permutation is red, then it paints the $(i+1)$-th ball in the permutation blue (if the latter is already blue, then it remains blue).
We secretly mark one of the red balls at the beginning. How many permutations are there in which our marked ball becomes blue by the end of the process?

I want to prove that the answer is

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}(-1)^j\frac{n!2^{k-2-j}{{k-1}\choose{j}}(k-1-j)}{n-j}.
$$

To show this, I was trying to use the inclusion-exclusion principle without success. How could we derive this formula?

ps.: There are other (maybe nicer) formulas that would work, but I am particularly interested in the one given above.

**Edit:** Thank you for all the great answers so far! My main question, however, remains open: how to prove that the formula I proposed is correct?

Comment: In other words, the marked red ball should follow another red ball in the permutation, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, and the red ball before the marked should not be preceded by another red ball, unless it is preceded by another red one, etc.

Comment: So, you only do $n-1$ ticks? Also, what is "the $i$-th ball"?

Comment: Is it a permutation of labeled or unlabeled balls? In other words, are the balls of the same color distinguishable?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis, you are right, it would be clearer to say that there are only $n-1$ ticks. The $i$-th ball is the ball at index $i$ in the permutation. Fixed the questions so that this is clear now.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev, The balls are labelled, so there are $n!$ permutations.

Comment: The straightforward inclusion-exclusion on the length of the run of red balls up to the marked ball gives $$(k-1) \sum_{j=0}^{k-2} (-1)^j \frac{(k-2)!(n-1-j)!}{(k-2-j)!}$$but the term values differ from your sum. It might still be worth rearranging your sum as $$(k-1) \sum_{j=0}^{k-2}(-1)^j\frac{n!2^{k-2-j} \binom{k-2}{j}}{n-j}$$since the $(k-1)$ and $\binom{k-2}j$ have easy combinatorial explanations.

Comment: The expression in my answer coincides with your conjectured (?) expression for $n=1,\dots,40$ and $k=1,\dots,n$. I think it could be helpful if you can disclose how you arrived at your expression (and also, perhaps, why it is of interest).

Comment: Based on computer evaluations, I am quite confident that my formula is correct. I am also interested in the problem when for the $i$-th tick, if the $i$-th ball is red, then it colors both the $(i+1)$-th and the $(i+2)$-th ball blue (now we have only $n-2$ ticks). My formula nicely transfers to this more complicated problem. My aim is to give upper bound on the probability of a red ball turning blue --- this does not look easy with the other formulas posted in this thread even for the simper version of the problem. But maybe I am wrong in this regard.

Comment: @macat: My approach well extends to this variation as well.

Comment: @macat : (i) It should be pretty straightforward to modify my approach to the case of the two subsequent balls changing the color. (ii) The advantage of my expression is that all terms in it are positive, which should make it significantly easier to upper-bound (and to lower-bound) it. What kind of upper bound are you looking for?

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis, In the setting of the original question, I want to prove that the probability of the marked red ball going blue is at most $1/3$ if $n\geq 2(k-1)+1$ (we can assume $n = 2(k-1)+1$). It would be a nice addition to see that the probability for $k$ and $n = 2(k-1)+1$ goes to $1/3$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Note that $n = 2(k-1)+1$ is the smallest number of balls where all $k$ red balls may remain red.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev, It is not clear how to work with your expression. I do not insist to my formula if I can show the bound mentioned in the previous comment for another one.

Comment: @macat : (i) I have further simplified the expression, which is now very easy to analyze. (ii) Now it is also proved that, for $n=2k-1$, indeed $1/3$ is the exact upper bound on the probability of the marked red ball turning blue and this probability goes to $1/3$ as $k\to\infty$.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis, Thank you. I am trying to generailse your formula for the more complicated case I mentioned in the comments (when two consequtive balls become blue instead of just one). I wonder how complicated it is going to be.

Comment: @macat: Switching to the variation amounts to replacing the expression $(r_2 + r_3 + 2(r_4+r_5) + \dots)$, which stands for the number of suitable places for the marked ball, with $(r_2 + 2(r_3+r_4) + 3r_5 + 4(r_6+r_7) + 5r_8 + \dots)$ or alike. Otherwise it goes along the same lines.

Comment: @Max Alekseyev, I am sure this would give the right formula, but how would I prove my upper bound to that variant of the formula? (I can not prove it even for the easier case.)

Comment: I can still not see how to generalize the formula of @Iosif Pinelis without the sums getting very ugly.

Comment: @macat : The all-positive-terms expression in my answer is substantially simpler than your conjectured alternating-sign expression. Moreover, the all-positive expression is proved (rather than conjectured) and, moreover, used to prove the desired bound and asymptotics. No such prospects for your conjectured expression are in sight and can hardly be expected. It appears that my approach has so far the best prospects to be extended to two balls changing the color.

Comment: Previous comment continued: However, (i) the two-ball setting is not mentioned in your post, (ii) this modified setting, briefly mentioned only in a comment of yours, is open to different interpretations (in my view), and (iii) your conjectured expression does not seem to have a good chance to be proved and then successfully used. Therefore, the present question seems now ripe for a resolution, and the two-ball setting could be explained in detail in a separate post.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis, This question did not turned out as I hoped it would, and my question remains unanswered. Nevertheless, I found the discussion extremely helpful, and I am greatfull for your time. The formula you suggested is indeed simpler than anything I had before (including my conjectured formula)! Should I fail to extend it for the desired problem, I will ask for help in a new question in a few days. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us put an additional blue ball in position $0$, to the left of the $n$ balls.
The condition on the permutations of the $n$ balls is then that the marked red ball be preceded by an odd number (say $2r-1$) of red balls, which in turn must be preceded by a blue ball. Let us refer to such permutations as good.
Let $p_{n,k}$ denote the number of good permutations of the $k$ red balls and $n-k$ blue ones.

Let $j$ be the position of the marked red ball in a good permutation. Then $j\ge2r$.

If $j=2r$, then $j$ is even and the only blue ball to the left of the marked red ball is the additional blue ball in position $0$. So, for any given even $j\in[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, the number of good permutations with $2r=j$ is
\begin{equation*}
    \Big(\prod_{i=0}^{j-2}(k-1-i)\Big)(n-j)!=\frac{(k-1)!(n-j)!}{(k-j)!}. 
\end{equation*}
(If $j>k$, then the latter fraction is understood as $0$.)

Similarly counted are the good permutations with $j>2r$, where we must use one of the $n-k$ blue balls to place it immediately to the left of the $2r-1$ red balls preceding the marked red ball.

Thus,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    p_{n,k}&=\sum_{j\in[n]}\Big(
    1(j\text{ is even})\frac{(k-1)!(n-j)!}{(k-j)!} \\ 
    &+\sum_{1\le r<j/2}(n-k)\frac{(k-1)!(n-2r-1)!}{(k-2r)!}
    \Big) \\ 
&=(k-1)!\sum_{j\in[k]}
    1(j\text{ is even})\frac{(n-j)!}{(k-j)!} \\ 
    &+(k-1)!(n-k)   
    \sum _{r=1}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor } \frac{(n-2 r)!}{(k-2 r)!} \\ 
    &=(k-1)!(n-k+1) 
    \sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor } \frac{(n-2 r)!}{(k-2 r)!}.   
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

---

This very simple expression is easy to analyze. Indeed, consider what is, according to the OP's comment, the case of interest: $n=2k-1$. Then
\begin{equation*}
    p_{n,k}=q_k:=p_{2k-1,k}=k!\sum_{r=1}^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor } \frac{(2k-1-2 r)!}{(k-2 r)!}.
\end{equation*}
The OP wanted to show that
\begin{equation*}
    P_k:=\frac{q_k}{(2k-1)!}
\end{equation*}
is $\le1/3$ and $P_k\to1/3$ as $k\to\infty$.

To prove this, write
\begin{equation*}
    P_k=\sum_{r=1}^\infty a_{k,r}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    a_{k,r}:=\frac{k!}{(2k-1)!} \frac{(2k-1-2 r)!}{(k-2 r)!};
\end{equation*}
the latter fraction is understood as $0$ if $2r>k$. We can also write
\begin{equation*}
    a_{k,r}=\prod_{i=0}^{2r-1}\frac{k-i}{2k-1-i}
    =\frac{k}{2k-1}\prod_{i=1}^{2r-1}\frac{k-i}{2k-1-i}
    \le \frac{k}{2k-1}\frac1{2^{2r-1}}. 
\end{equation*}
It also follows that $a_{k,r}\to\frac1{2^{2r}}$ as $k\to\infty$, for each natural $r$. So, by \eqref{1} and dominated convergence,
\begin{equation*}
    P_k\to\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac1{2^{2r}}=\frac13, \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
as was desired.

Next, it is easy to see that, for each natural $r\ge2$, $a_{k,r}$ is increasing in natural $k\ge2r$. A little complication here is that $a_{k,1}$ is decreasing in $k$. However, it is rather easy to see that $\sum_{r=1}^3 a_{k,r}$ is increasing in natural $k\ge5$. So, by \eqref{1}, $P_k$ is increasing in natural $k\ge5$.
So, by \eqref{2}, $P_k<1/3$ for $k\ge5$. It also easy to see that $P_k<1/3$ for $k\in\{1,3,4\}$ and $P_2=1/3$.
Thus, $P_2=1/3$ and $P_k<1/3$ for $k\in\{1,3,4,5,6,\dots\}$, as was also desired.

Answer (score 2):

If we view permutation as runs of red balls interspaced with runs of blue balls, then the requirement is that the marked ball is at the even position within its run.

Let $t$ be the number of red runs; $r_i$ and $b_i$ be the number of red and blue runs of length $i$, respectively.

\begin{split}
& (n-k)!(k-1)!\sum_{t\geq 0} \sum_{1r_1 + 2r_2 + \dots = k\atop r_1 + \dots + r_k = t} \binom{t}{r_1,\dots,r_n} (r_2 + r_3 + 2(r_4+r_5) + \dots) \\
&\quad\times \bigg(2\sum_{1b_1 + 2b_2 + \dots = n-k\atop b_1 + \dots + b_k = t} \binom{t}{b_1,\dots,b_n} +\sum_{1b_1 + 2b_2 + \dots = n-k\atop b_1 + \dots + b_k = t-1} \binom{t-1}{b_1,\dots,b_n} +\sum_{1b_1 + 2b_2 + \dots = n-k\atop b_1 + \dots + b_k = t+1} \binom{t+1}{b_1,\dots,b_n} \bigg) \\
&=(n-k)!(k-1)!\sum_{t\geq 0} \sum_{1r_1 + 2r_2 + \dots = k\atop r_1 + \dots + r_k = t} \binom{t}{r_1,\dots,r_n} (r_2 + r_3 + 2(r_4+r_5) + \dots) \\
&\quad\times \bigg(2\binom{n-k-1}{t-1} + \binom{n-k-1}{t-2} + \binom{n-k-1}{t} \bigg) \\
&=(n-k)!(k-1)!\sum_{t\geq 0} \sum_{1r_1 + 2r_2 + \dots = k\atop r_1 + \dots + r_k = t} \binom{t}{r_1,\dots,r_n} (r_2 + r_3 + 2(r_4+r_5) + \dots)\binom{n-k+1}{t} \\
&=(n-k)!(n-k+1)!\frac1{k}\sum_{t\geq 0} \frac1{(n-k+1-t)!}\sum_{1r_1 + 2r_2 + \dots = k\atop r_1 + \dots + r_k = t} \frac{k!}{r_1!\cdots r_n!} (r_2 + r_3 + 2(r_4+r_5) + \dots)
\end{split}

In terms of [Bell polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials) this can be written as
$$=(n-k)!(n-k+1)!\frac1{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left.\sum_{t\geq 0} \frac1{(n-k+1-t)!} B_{k}(1!,2!x,3!x,4!x^2,5!x^2,\dots)\right|_{x=1}$$
Then using the generating function for Bell polynomials we have

\begin{split}
&\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sum_{t\geq 0} \frac1{(n-k+1-t)!} B_{k}(1!,2!x,3!x,4!x^2,5!x^2,\dots)\right|_{x=1} \\
&= k!\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x} [y^{n-k+1}t^k]\ \exp(y) \exp(y (t + xt^2 + xt^3 + x^2t^4 + x^2t^5 +\dots))\right|_{x=1} \\
&= \frac{k!}{(n-k+1)!}[t^k] \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(1 + t + xt^2 + xt^3 + x^2t^4 + x^2t^5 +\dots)^{n-k+1}\right|_{x=1} \\
&=\frac{k!}{(n-k)!} [t^k]\ (1+ t + t^2 + t^3 + \dots)^{n-k} (t^2 + t^3 + 2t^4 + 2t^5 + \dots) \\
& = \frac{k!}{(n-k)!} [t^k] \frac{t^2}{(1-t)^{n-k+2}(1+t)} \\
& = \frac{k!}{(n-k)!} (-1)^k \sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \binom{-(n-k+2)}{k-j-2} \\
& = \frac{k!}{(n-k)!} \sum_{j=0}^{k-2} (-1)^j \binom{n-j-1}{k-j-2}.
\end{split}
All in all, we get the answer:
$$(n-k+1)!(k-1)! \sum_{j=0}^{k-2} (-1)^j \binom{n-j-1}{k-j-2} = (k-1)! \sum_{j=0}^{k-2} (-1)^j \frac{(n-j-1)!}{(k-j-2)!}.$$

Comment: Thank you for showing me this approach, it has been instructive. The final formula does not coincide with the one in my question, and it also seems harder to work with for my purposes compared to the one derived in the accepted answer.